# Illustrator 2020 Snapping relative to Cursor Position

Tags: adobe-illustrator, tools, selections, snapping

With the latest Illustrator update, snapping has been all wonky. When dragging objects before the update, I was able to snap the object's edge or center to the guides from the edge or center of another object. Now, the update has caused everything to snap based on the cursor's location when I start dragging the object, which doesn't seem useful at all.

Is there a way to disable this feature or revert it? I'd rather not have take multiple steps when aligning my objects by zooming in and click on the furthest anchor points on two sides.

I have tried turning on and off all snapping options, smart guides, checking every option in preferences, but I cannot find anything that says snap to cursor vs. bounding box.

Comment: LOL, and imagine that people have requested this feature several time. Not understanding that direct selection allready did this...